# UIButton Buy Now effect

Tags: objective-c, animation, resize, uibutton, app-store

I want to make a "Buy Now" button in my Application, which should work the same way as the one in the App Store, but I dont know how to resize the UIButton with an animation.

I have tried the following, but it resized the button at once and not as an animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:10.5];
[buyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 115, 70, 21)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Where the "buyButton" is a UIButton.

I've checked ou this post [UIButton AppStore buy button animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669804/uibutton-appstore-buy-button-animation), but is does not seem to work.

Comment: Your code worked for me.  You realize that 10.5 seconds is a really long time?  Are you sure that the frame you've chosen isn't exactly the same as what the button already is.  Make sure this code executes when you hit the button and not before.  Also use an NSLog statement in that code snippet so you can check the log and see if it executes twice without you knowing.  Seeing more of your code might help, like: where in your program does this code reside?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scalingFactorX, scalingFactorY);
buyButton.transform = scale;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Using `CGAffineTransform` may help. I have not tried this, however, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

the sample code on theapptree.com for the inapp purchase should do what you want.

http://www.theapptree.com/samples